# When embeding my Google map it is fully zoomed out on my site, but when following the link directly it is correctly zoomed in

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I have just created a custom public map on google.maps
Here is a link to it: [my custom map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zDPZ70Xno_3g.k5EUl8d_poK0)
As you can see it's pretty zoomed in on the locaiton with my custom icon..
But when I have it embeded on my site it is zoomed out so far that i can see from Croatia to Turkey and it isn't even centered on my location.

See for yourself: [image]

This is the code I use to embed the map

```
<iframe id="mapframe" src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zDPZ70Xno_3g.k5EUl8d_poK0" width="700" height="400" frameborder="0" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

and then in css all I have is `#mapframe{float:left;}`

I also noticed that in Chrome when I refresh the page several times the map gets zoomed in properly, but not in Safari or Firefox.. If you want to see it live here's my site [D&P profimedia](http://www.dpprofimedia.cz) you'll first have to click the circle in the midle and then mouse over the *i* centered at the top of the page and there you click on "KONTAKT"

I've spent most of my shift looking for a solution but nothing I tried worked.

The map is in an hidden fullscreen overlay on my page, that is only displayed after the user clicks on the info button, could that have anything to do with the map not zooming in properly?

I'll be very thankful for any tips and ideas you give me.

**UPDATE 3**
I just tried replacing the `iframe` tags with `embed` and it did solve it in Safari and Chrome at least on my Mac. But Firefox is now showing only a grey box, with "missing plugin" in the center [(screenshot)](http://puu.sh/htTkb/4131f6d669.png). I found out that I should put the `embed` into `object` with  the same properties, so I did that so the code I have now looks like this:

```
<object class="mapframe" type="text/html" data="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zDPZ70Xno_3g.k5EUl8d_poK0" height="400" width="700" frameborder="0" style="border:0;">
    <embed class="mapframe" src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zDPZ70Xno_3g.k5EUl8d_poK0" height="400" width="700" frameborder="0" style="border:0;">
</object>
```

But with it, it now dosn't work at all in Chrome [(result)](http://puu.sh/htTeI/ea0b2d7044.png) and it is zoomed out just as before in Firefox and Safari [(like this)](http://puu.sh/htTcX/2dae5e530e.png) .

I don't really understand why though...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that is wrong. What worked by me was the Google Maps JavScript API v3. The code you will need:

HTML (head):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
```

HTML (body):

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Javacsript:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.2333136, 12.8448827)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Change to `zoom` in the `mapOptions` array to what you want.

Comment: ok so I tried that. I only changed your '<div id="map-canvas"></div>' to '<div id="map-canvas" style="width:700px;height:400px;"></div>' and then i added the javascript inbetween '<script></script>' right beneath the '#map-canvas' and when I reloaded the page all I get is http://puu.sh/htSnn/1ec9d759fb.png for some reason the map doesn't fully render..